# Windows key + arrow, i.e. Aero Snap, performing differently in Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, aero-snap

Aero Snap in Windows 7 simply moved the active window.  In Windows 10 (for me now) the Windows key + arrows still move the active window but sometimes also displays thumbnails of the other windows and makes that display active.  When this happens I must press other keys to get back to my originally active window.

Oh, I just figured out when the other display appears - it happens when the originally active window is moved to the half of a screen that has no window displayed on the other half.  Apparently it is giving me the options available to fill that space with.

Is there a way to set the behavior to Windows 7 type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can edit this behavior.  Windows 10 has 'MultiTasking' options in Settings which will fix your problem.  In MultiTasking, turn off the setting 'When I snap a window, show what I can snap next to it".

When you turn this setting off, the window retains the focus (as it should by default in my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, if you use Windows-key + arrows it moves the focused window.
Assuming that you have a reason for e.g. putting browser window only at half display screen (because you want to show something else in the other half) Win10 suggests you all other open windows to just click on it.

If you do not want any other window on the other half screen, just press Esc after Win+cursor, then the selection disappears and the formlery window stays in focus.
But you probably already noticed that...

I dont get the point I think...what is the issue you have with the win10 behaviour?

Comment: The issue I have is extra input/time spent on using Windows.