# Windows 10 keyboard shortcut to dock window side effect

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I frequently use <kbd>win+left-arrow</kbd> to move a Window to the side.

Using Windows 10:

- when I release the <kbd>win</kbd> key
- and the Window I've moved is docked at that time

Windows shows all windows as a thumbnail and I have to press <kbd>esc</kbd> to return to my normal operation. Windows 7 did not have this behavior.

Anyone know a work around for that?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows key + arrow, i.e. Aero Snap, performing differently in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1257754/windows-key-arrow-i-e-aero-snap-performing-differently-in-windows-10)

Comment: @Owen - it is the same issue and solution but the wording is different enough for me to not find it when I need it. Not sure now what I have to do with closing this question or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn off this feature entirely & I'm guessing that will be your only solution:

> Windows Settings->System->Multitasking->untick 'When I snap a window, show what I can snap next to it'

Comment: You have no idea of how much frustration you've saved me...

Comment: Glad to help since it took me two seconds, you just had to know what the feature was called in Windows (Snap Assist or just Snap) to search for it :)

Comment: Now I know of the option I can see a use for it when using the mouse but being a keyboard nut, it's next to useless.